# Missing nodes() method in SQL Server 2008 RC2

Tags: sql-server-2008, xpath, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to query using a XPath expression. My Microsoft SQL Server 2008 RC2 knows the functions `value()` and `query()` but is missing the `nodes()` method.

Example:

```
SELECT Data.nodes('/root/ids/id') As id FROM myTable
```

Data is a XML column in the table `myTable`.

Is it required to install the `nodes()` method somehow?

Comment: Are you getting an error? What does the error say?

Comment: @AakashM `"nodes" is not a valid function, property, or field.` presumably.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`nodes` can return more than one row so you don't call it as though it returns a scalar

```
with myTable as
(
SELECT CAST('<root><ids><id>1</id><id>2</id></ids></root>' AS XML) AS Data
)

SELECT x.value('.', 'int')
FROM   myTable
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes('/root/ids/id') x(x)
```

Comment: What does "x(x)" mean?

Comment: @IanWarburton `x` is the name I gave to both the table alias and the column alias for the resultset of the `nodes` method. Obviously wasn't feeling particularly inspired to come up with something more imaginative at the time...